# Prediction in simple and multiple ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, confidence-interval

In a (one or multi) way anova model, once a new individual is assigned to a treatment, the predicted value for him is calculated using the coefficients of the ANOVA model (simply assigning the treatment mean value to the individual).

How should I construct a confidence (or prediction) interval for that predicted value? Can the `predict` function be used in R for an `aov` model?

There must be something that I'm missing here, as I can't find anything like this in my books. Thank you.

Comment: You added the `spss` tag, but your syntax looks like you are looking for an R solution. Correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lm()` instead of `aov()` in this case (the latter is a wrapper of the former).

Here is an illustration:

```
n <- 100
A <- gl(2, n/2, n, labels=paste("a", 1:2, sep=""))
B <- gl(2, n/4, n, labels=paste("b", 1:2, sep=""))
# generate fake data for a balanced two-way ANOVA
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(n), A, B)
summary(lm1 <- lm(y~A+B, data=df)) # compare with summary.aov(...)
predict(lm1, expand.grid(A=levels(A), B=levels(B)), interval="confidence")
```

The latter command gives you predictions for each combination of the A and B factor levels (here, I didn't included the interaction), in the following order:

```
   A  B
1 a1 b1
2 a2 b1
3 a1 b2
4 a2 b2
```

Another option is to use the [effects](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/index.html) package.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really liked the use of expand.grid here. Is it ok to use this procedure in unbalanced datasets or when some cells are totally missing observations?

Comment: Oh, I haven't used the effects package. Could you give me some tips on how it can be used here?

Comment: @Brani (1) R remove statistical units with missing values before estimating the effects; compare the above results (especially the DF for the residuals) with `summary(lm1 <- lm(y~A+B, data=df[-sample(1:nrow(df), 10),]))`. Of course, it is important to know whether data are missing at random or not, but see [Treatment of Missing Data](http://bit.ly/gISQy8) by Howell, for instance. (2) The `effects` package is useful to display predictions for complex models (e.g., incl. interaction). Here, you can try `plot(effect(term="A", mod=lm1))`, or browse the on-line, `help(effect)` for examples of use.